# Getting Number of check boxes in a div

Tags: jquery

I was wondering that if there is a way to get a number of checkboxes present in a div or anyother element.
Some thing like

```
$('div').find(':checkbox').number();
```

Please let me know if some function exists for this.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Comment: `.length` maybe?

Comment: @Doug is correct: `$('div').find(':checkbox').length` is the answer. Note that it will bring back the checkboxes in *all* div elements.

Comment: before you ask a question . at least do a Google research .  try something your self and ask when get in to trouble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/DK6GA/

```
$('div#example input[type="checkbox"]').length
```

example is the id

Answer (score 1):

Yup Pretty easy, here you go with a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/ENHr4/13/)